# Show white spaces in select combobox that is filled with knockout js binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I would like to be able to fill a HTML `select` element with a knockout binding. Some of the option texts include white spaces and I'd like to show them in the dropdown.

In pure HTML this can be accomplished by using `&nbsp;` instead of simple white spaces, but that's not working with the knockout binding:

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sp2J8/)

HTML:

```
Knockout select:
<select data-bind="options: entries" style="width: 150px"></select>
<br>
Standard select:
<select style="width: 150px">
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;Entry 1</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Entry 2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    entries = ko.observableArray([
        '&nbsp;&nbsp;Entry 1',
        '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Entry 2'
    ]);
};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Hope someone can help me with this!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular `foreach` instead of the `options` where you can set your html content with the [`html` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) on your option elements:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: entries" style="width: 150px">
    <option data-bind="html: $data"></option>
</select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvqBN/).